# glEnable doesn't compile inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, opengl, depth-buffer

I'm compiling OpenGL using freeglut and glew using visual studio. I'm having a rather strange issue and I have reduced the code to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>


class Test
{
public:
Test() { }
void enable();
};

void Test::enable()
{
    //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)​; // Doesn't compile? Error - Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';'   

}

int main()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

Comment: (OT backslash in included file paths... oh, the horror, the horror)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Fixed but not the issue

Comment: Between ) and ; there is odd invisible character in the commented out line. Possibly it got there by some copy-paste from some web site. Erase that line and write again.

Comment: Thank you very much! very strange. No idea how you managed to find that...